# validates_format_of in rails (only numbers, commas and white spaces)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation

I have a field "floors" and I want it to accept only numbers, commas and white spaces.

I'm using a `validates_format_of :floors, :with => /[0-9\,\s]+/` right now, but it works bad because it accepts a string like "1, 2, abc".

Please help me to find my mistake.

Comment: Use anchors: `/\A[0-9,\s]+\z/`. But this will also match `, , , 123, 33,,33`-like strings. Do you only want to match float numbers?

Comment: Thanks. Please post it as answer so I could mark it as accepted. Also maybe you can explain a little bit

Comment: It would be great if a first symbol should be a number (not a comma)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex matches `1, 2,`  inside `1, 2, abc`, it is a partial match. To disallow partial matches, use start-of-string and end-of-string anchors.

In Ruby, to match the start of the string you need to use `\A` anchor. The end-of-string anchor is `\z`. Thus, use

```
/\A[0-9,\s]+\z/
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cD8eV6/1)

Also note that `,` is not a special regex metacharacter and does not need escaping.

If you need to start with a number, you can use

```
/\A\d[\d,\s]*\z/
```

Here, `\d` will require a digit to appear in the beginning and then it can be followed with digits, whitespace and commas, zero or more occurrences. Another way of restricting the generic character class is using a lookahead: `\A(?=\d)[\d,\s]+\z`.

Going further, you can match numbers like `1,300,567.567` or `1 300 567.567` with

```
/\A\d{1,3}(?:[,\s]\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?\z/
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/cD8eV6/2)

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer!

Comment: I added some more just in case :) Glad to help. You can further check these patterns at [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) to see which variant works for you best.